No entra dentro de mi if el codigo y se sigue al else
Claro, aquí tienes una extensión del texto:
Estoy inmerso en un proyecto bastante desafiante que requiere la integración de VBA y ASP.NET con el patrón MVC. Desde hace un tiempo, he estado dedicando esfuerzos al desarrollo de un código que facilite la conexión de la aplicación a una base de datos. Este componente es fundamental para garantizar la funcionalidad de la aplicación y permitir la gestión eficiente de los datos.
No obstante, me he topado con un obstáculo significativo al intentar presentar los datos en una tabla dentro de la vista de mi aplicación. A pesar de los avances que he logrado en la conexión con la base de datos, parece que la transición de los datos desde el modelo hasta la vista no está funcionando como esperaba.
La tabla en cuestión debería mostrar una lista de registros que residen en la base de datos. He verificado minuciosamente mi código para detectar posibles errores, pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito en identificar la causa subyacente del problema. Esta situación me ha llevado a reflexionar sobre la complejidad de la integración entre distintas tecnologías y la importancia de comprender a fondo los aspectos técnicos de cada una de ellas.
Este desafío me ha brindado una oportunidad invaluable para mejorar mis habilidades de resolución de problemas y para profundizar mi comprensión de los entornos de desarrollo en los que trabajo. Aunque el proceso puede resultar frustrante en ocasiones, estoy decidido a encontrar una solución que me permita avanzar en este proyecto y alcanzar mis objetivos.
<div class="Tabla">
        <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_nombre()" type="text" name="search" placeholder="buscar empleado...">
        <table id="example" class="ui celled table " width="100%" align="Center" style=" overflow-x: scroll;">
            <thead>
                <tr class="titulos" style="justify-content:center; align-items:center; margin-left:auto;">
                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>PUESTO</th>
                    <th>FECHA DE INGRESO</th>
                    <th>CALIFICACIÓN</th>
                    <th>ULTIMA EVALUACIÓN</th>
                    <th>SIGUIENTE EVALUACIÓN</th>
                    <th>VENCIMIENTO DE EVALUACIÓN</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if ViewData("ReportList") IsNot Nothing Then
                    @For Each item In ViewData("ReportList")
                         @<tr>
                              <td>@item.nombre</td>
                              <td>@item.puesto</td>
                              <td>@item.fecha_de_ingreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                              <td>@item.calificacion</td>
                              <td>@item.ultima_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                              <td>@item.siguiente_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                              <td>@item.vencimiento_de_evaluacion.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                              <td>@item.status</td>
                         </tr>
                    Next
                Else
                    @<tr>
                         <td> esto falla </td>
                    </tr>
                End If

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

A pesar de que la tabla en mi base de datos contiene 15 registros, al intentar mostrarlos en la tabla de mi vista, no aparece ningún dato. He revisado mi código y no logro identificar cuál podría ser el problema.
He comparado mi código con otros proyectos en los que he trabajado y en los cuales esta funcionalidad ha sido exitosa, pero no encuentro una diferencia significativa.
Me preocupa que el problema pueda estar en la vista, ya que es el único lugar en el que no he podido identificar algún error evidente. He intentado modificar el controlador y también la vista, pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito.
¿Podrías ayudarme a identificar cuál podría ser el error? Agradezco cualquier orientación o sugerencia que puedas proporcionarme para resolver este problema.

mm que tiene que ver vba con este problema? de paso.. al parecer tu modelo no esta devolviendo datos... estas seguro que devuelve algo, en esa variable que vos decis? mostra ese codigo...

No te voy a decir qué opino del uso de IA para generar preguntas para SO... sinceramente, quieres que nos esforcemos en responderte pero tú no tienes pensado esforzarte ni un poquito en elaborar la pregunta correctamente tú mismo y prefieres usar una IA.. pues que te responda ella. Si buscas que alguien se esfuerce por responderte, lo mínimo es ser el primero en esforzarse al preguntar.

Deberías de tomarte la molestia al menos de redactar tú personalmente la pregunta.

una disculpa inges ese dia andaba super estresado pero gracias por sus comentarios me ayudaron mucho a ver que puedo mejorar

actualice mi pregunta por si decean expresar su opinion sobre ella muchas gracias
